# make private array inside function unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I have this code which works fine.

```
public string[] log;

void ApplyText(){
    notification.text = log[Random.Range(0,log.Length)];
}
```

But I want to do all the work in the script and if possible in single function
Maybe like this:-

```
 void ApplyText(){
    string[] log;
    log[0] = "hhyyhy";
    log[1] = "qwerty";
    log[2] = "poiyu";
    notification.text = log[Random.Range(0,3)];
 }
```

thanks, A lot.

Comment: So, what is your question? Ps, you should use: `string[] log = new string[3];`

Comment: Okay, I am Ashamed and Thank you @Stefan

Comment: No worries, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You laready had it almost but you have to initialize your array before filling it with values:

```
void ApplyText()
{
    var log = new string[3];

    log[0] = "hhyyhy";
    log[1] = "qwerty";
    log[2] = "poiyu";

    notification.text = log[Random.Range(0,3)];
}
```

or a bit simplier to read and more flexible in the future (if adding, removing entries):

```
void ApplyText()
{
    var log = new []
    {
        "hhyyhy",
        "qwerty",
        "poiyu"
    };

    notification.text = log[Random.Range(0, log.Length)];
}
```